# incomplete retrieved string from mysqli DB, PHP statement

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I am filling an edit form from a database, so i retrieve text from a database field and place it in an input text as follows:

```
    echo '<b> Topic: </b><input type = text size = 50 value = ' . $filler['LP_Topic'].'>'. $br;
```

it works fine, but it only gets the first word of the topic, not the whole string!

if I just echo the result without an input it will work perfectly ! the problem happens when I add  input 
regards

Comment: $filler is the retrieved row

Comment: Remove `size = 50` from the input.

Comment: You also need quotes around the value of ```value=```.

Comment: it was without it and didnt work then I added it hoping it solves the problem, but it didnt. so it doesnt work in both cases!

Comment: Thanks Sloan Thrasher, quotes solved the problem!

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please accept my answer below. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding quotes around the value. All html properties/attributes are supposed to be quoted.

```
echo '<b> Topic: </b><input type="text" size="50" value="' . $filler['LP_Topic'].'">'. $br;
```